# how to operate on a different port?

Tags: docker, symfony

with port 80 it works but I want it to work with port 82.

```
/php/Dockerfile
/php/vhosts/managerapi/vhosts.conf
/my-project
docker-compose.yml
```

here are the 3 files concerned :

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  manager-api:
    build: php
    container_name: www_docker_symfony_manager_api
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8002:82
    volumes:
      - ./php/vhosts/managerapi:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./my-project:/var/www/my-project
    networks:
      - dev
networks:
  dev:
```

php/Dockerfile

```yaml
FROM    php:8.0-apache

....

RUN     docker-php-ext-install zip pdo pdo_mysql opcache calendar dom intl mbstring xsl
RUN     pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu

# 
EXPOSE 82 

#
WORKDIR /var/www/my-project
```

/php/vhosts/managerapi/vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:82>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

It works fine on port 80.
I would like it to work on port 82, What is the problem?
please help me

windows 10 - symfony

Comment: Why do you want to change it?  Because of Docker's internal networking setup, using port 80 (the default HTTP port) won't conflict between containers, and your `ports:` remap it for non-Docker callers.

Answer (score 0):

Ports used by your docker container won't bind to your physical ports unless you bind it as you have in the .compose file and also will not interfere with other containers.

The limitation is only when you want it to bind to a physical port on your host which will be a one-to-one mapping.